# android notification image not as expected

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

i want to have notification image fit the height of the notification like this:

[image]

but what i see is like this:

[image]

my code is:

```
Client client = new Client(Configuration.getServer());
String str = client.getBaseURI("offers");
try {
    JSONArray json = new JSONArray(str);
    for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject oneOffer = json.getJSONObject(i);
        int offerID = oneOffer.getInt("ID");
        String offerDescriptoin = oneOffer.getString("Description");
        String endDate = oneOffer.getString("EndDate");
        String startDate = oneOffer.getString("StartDate");
        JSONObject restaurant = oneOffer.getJSONObject("Restaurant");
        int restaruantID = restaurant.getInt("ID");
        String restaurantName = restaurant.getString("Name");
        Offer offer = new Offer(offerID, startDate, endDate,
                offerDescriptoin, new Restaurant(restaruantID,
                        restaurantName));
        Log.d("DES", offerDescriptoin);
        Offer.getAllOffers().put(offer.getID(), offer);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, OfferNotification.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                intent, 0);
        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)

                .setContentTitle("Offer from " + restaurantName)
                .setContentText(offerDescriptoin).setSound(soundUri);
        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, OfferNotification.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra("offerID", offer.getID());
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

        stackBuilder.addParentStack(OfferNotification.class);

        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder
                .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotificationManager.notify(offer.getID(), mBuilder.build());
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

i mean the photon in the second case (second photo )is small and the text becomes under it, but i want like the first case when the photo is in all the height and the text left to the photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [Notifications UI guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html). You may want to use
 
`setLargeIcon(aBitmap)`
 method from NotificationCompat.Builder (for devices prior Android 3.0) or Notification.Builder instead of setSmallIcon.